# Does working directory change inside of a function?

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 1.0.1 with the Juno IDE.

I wrote a module MyModule,

```
 myModule

 using Gadfly, DataFrames, Cairo, Fontconfig 

 function foo(N::Int64)

      grid = 1:N
      df = DataFrame(x = grid, y = grid .^2)

      p = plot(x = "x", y = "y");
      draw(PNG("figures/plot.png", 6inch, 3inch), p)

 end

 end
```

Let's call the parent directory "Top". I have a file named `main.jl` located in `Top/Julia`. I also have some auxiliary functions located in `Top/Julia/functions`. The script `main.jl` consists of the following commands:

```
 using MyModule

 include("functions/auxiliaryFunction.jl")

 N = 10

 foo(10)
```

When I run this code,

1. The `include("functions/auxiliaryFunction.jl")` command works perfectly.
2. The file `plot.png` is created inside the directory `Top/figures` instead of inside of `Top/Julia/figures`

If I run `pwd()` in the REPL, it returns `".../Top"`. So what appears to be happening is that the working directory in the main script is the location of the file itself (or, of the "project" in Juno...kind of confused about that), whereas the working directory of the functions it calls in the modules it imports is the working directory of the REPL. Is this correct or am I missing something? What is the standard solution to this problem - add the working directory as an argument to the function?

**Edit 1:** If I add

```
 a = pwd()
 println("$a")
```

to the script `main.jl`, it returns

```
 .../Top
```

**Edit 2:** When `main.jl` is open in Atom, the top bar displays "main.jl --- ~/Top"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Atom/Juno IDE can sometimes have some weird effect on the working dir. I think this has to do with the project management. Have you tried closing Juno, and restarting it by opening `main.jl` in the `(...)/top/Julia` folder? Code seems fine to me.

Comment: Tried this, it didn't seem to work. When I open `main.jl` directly with Atom after closing Juno, it looks the same as before I closed it. I do believe this has to do with project management.